# Highlight another nav item

Tags: menus, navigation, wp-list-pages

I am using WordPress to develop a picture gallery website. I have albums and galleries, with different permalinks...`http://url.com/albums` and `http://url.com/gallery`, but only the albums appear in the main navigation.

The code for my navigation looks like:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_pages("title_li="); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Because I am using the `wp_list_pages()` function, the current page that you're on gets a `current_page_item` class added to the `li` tag.

The gallery page is not part of the main navigation, so when someone is viewing one of the gallery pages, nothing is highlighted in the main navigation.

I'd like to highlight the album page in the main navigation when someone is viewing a gallery page. Because each gallery is in album, it makes sense to highlight that page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What is a gallery, a page, a custom post type? You can filter the css classes in the menu, you just need to be able to identify when you're viewing a gallery.

Comment: Hey there, I am using a plugin called Envira Gallery (http://enviragallery.com) to create the gallery. I was looking through the code and it does look like it uses a post type called "envira".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`page_css_class` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_css_class/) lets you modify the classes each menu item gets.

Here we check if we are currently viewing a singular `envira` post type and the menu item slug is `gallery`. In that case we add a class to the array of default classes passed to the function.

```
function wpd_page_css_class( $css_class, $page ){
    if( is_singular( 'envira' ) && 'albums' == $page->post_name ){
        $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
    }
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'wpd_page_css_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hey there, I added this to my `functions.php` file, but it didn't seem to do anything...I was able to find a solution though (see below) and appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: oh, I suppose you wanted `album` highlighted, not `gallery`.

Comment: Yes I did, I'm sorry, I should've been more specific.

Comment: I went back and added your solution, changing gallery to albums and it worked! I apologize for not understanding your function...if you'll update your code, I'll make sure to choose this as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

After some poking around, I found my answer here: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-addclass-to-containing-li-based-on-a-href-contents from Przemek (4th comment down).

All I did was make sure that the code is only executed on the gallery page:

```
<?php if ( is_singular("envira") ) { ?>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('li.page_item').find('a[href*="/albums/"]').parent().addClass('current_page_item');
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

This works, because it finds the list item with the albums permalink and adds the class I need. If I ever change the page order, the script will still work. The only time this would be an issue is if my permalink changes, but for this site, that is not an issue.

Thanks,
Josh